# The conditional use of 'could' in the movie quotes

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

Consider this dialog:

> Dwight: It's your apartment. But be careful, Shellie, this clown's got a big, mean drunk-on and he's got four friends out there in the hall, breathing hard and just as drunk as he is.
>
> Jackie Boy: Hey, I **could** swear I heard somebody in there with you just now.
>
> Shellie: Somebody? Jackie Boy, it's a regular African love fest in here!
>
> Jackie Boy: - I'm no racist.
>
> Shellie: I mean, I got me all five starters, and half the bench of the Basin City Blues keeping me company. You feel like taking them on?
>
> Jackie Boy: You are teasing me, baby. Some of my best friends... but you are really pushing my buttons and the whole time you've been doing me like this, I've been too polite to point out that at any time I want to I **could** kick this damn door to splinters.
>
> -- *Sin City* 2005

What's the use of the two bold **could**? Is it possible to use **can** instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uses of could in both cases is conditional. In the first example, the expression **I could swear** is quite common when you're almost sure of something - so sure, that you *could* swear to it.

In the second example, **if he wanted to**, he *could* break the door down.

The "African love fest" they're referring would be composed of black people. He's basically saying that he would be happy to join in because he doesn't discriminate against black people.

Comment: Thx.  And what does he mean by **drunk-on**? Is it an adjective?

Comment: it's actually a noun, made by analogy with "hard-on" which means "erection." So just like "he's got a hard-on" would mean that his dick has gotten hard, "he's got a drunk-on" would mean that he's gotten quite drunk, in a colloquial, roundabout way :)

Comment: Wow, interesting! Is it an idiom, or Jackie Boy (screen writer) improvised it there?

Comment: it's definitely idiomatic and you hear it from time to time with different components, always on the analogy of "having a hard-on." I've even heard it used in reference to women: "she's got a hard-on for him" meaning she has a crush on him.

Comment: I've got a shake-on for that. :-)